# Escape double quotes JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following line which isn't working

```
 var roomname = JSON.stringify(item.name.replace("\"",""));
```

So clearly doing this isn't working "\""
How can I escape the double quote?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It seems `item.name` is already a string; why are you trying to pass it through `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: That's true, I just changed it. Anyways I still want to escape the double quotes

Comment: Wait sorry, that made them go away! Thank you

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking here. Do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the quote to apostrophe.

```
var roomname = JSON.stringify(item.name.replace('\"',''));
```

Comment: Why escape the double-quote in `'\"'`